# Haskell: How can I implement an applicative functor on own map data type?

Tags: dictionary, haskell, functor, applicative

I am very new to Haskell and I wrote a Data Type in Haskell
for representing an interval map.

What does that mean? Briefly: A map data type that gives you a value back
for every possible key (put simply in my case [0..]).

Then you insert "sequences" like I want my map to hold from 7 to 23 'b'
so keys 0 to 6 will be init value e.g. 'a' and 7 to 23 will be 'b' and 24 and ongoing will be 'a' again etc.

I managed to wrote the Data Type, a get and insert function as well as a
functor version.

But I can't managed to get a applicative functor version to work.
The idea is to set the keys value to [0..] and just work on the values.

Here is my code and thanks for any provided help!

```hs
-- Building an interval map data structure in haskell

data IntervalMap k v = IntervalMap {keys :: [k] , values :: [v]} | Empty deriving Show
-- k = key, Typ variable 
-- v = value, Typ variable

singleton :: (Enum k, Num k) => v -> IntervalMap k v
singleton v = IntervalMap{keys=[0..], values= repeat v}

-- get operator => a ! 5 = value at position 5
(!) :: Ord k => IntervalMap k v -> k -> v
(!) iMap k = snd (head (filter (\(x, y) -> x == k) (zip (keys iMap) (values iMap)) ))

-- insert a sequence into intervalMap
insert :: (Ord k, Num k, Enum k) => k -> k -> v -> IntervalMap k v -> IntervalMap k v
insert start end value iMap = IntervalMap {keys=keys iMap, values = rangeChanger (values iMap) start end value}

-- helper function to change a range of values in an intervalMap
rangeChanger :: (Num a1, Enum a1, Ord a1) => [a2] -> a1 -> a1 -> a2 -> [a2]
rangeChanger iMapValues start end value = [if (i >= start) && (i <= end) then newValue else iMapValue | (iMapValue, newValue, i) <- zip3 iMapValues (repeat value) [0..]]


-- functor instance for intervalMap
instance Functor (IntervalMap k) where
    -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b 
    fmap f iMap = IntervalMap {keys=keys iMap, values= map f (values iMap) }


-- applicative functor for intervalMap
instance (Ord k, Num k, Enum k) => Applicative (IntervalMap k) where
pure k = IntervalMap{keys=[0..], values=repeat k}
_ <*> Nothing  = Nothing  
-- HOW TO DO?

-- class Functor functor => Applicative functor where
--  pure :: a -> functor a
--  (<*>) :: functor (a -> b) -> functor a -> functor b
--  (*>) :: functor a -> functor b -> functor b
--  (<*) :: functor a -> functor b -> functor a
```

Comment: Shouldn't `pure` be the same as `singleton`, i.e. `repeat k` instead of `[k]`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's my bad

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you always expect the keys to be `[0..]`, e.g. it is hard-coded in your `rangeChanger` function. If that is the case then it is redundant and honestly I would leave it out. You can easily reconstruct it by doing something like `zip [0..] (values iMap)` as you do in the `rangeChanger` function.

If you make that change, then your `IntervalMap` data structure is basically the same as [`ZipList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList) which has an applicative instance [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/Control-Applicative.html#instance%20Applicative%20ZipList):

> ```hs
> instance Applicative ZipList where
>     pure x = ZipList (repeat x)
>     liftA2 f (ZipList xs) (ZipList ys) = ZipList (zipWith f xs ys)
> ```

You see that this doesn't define a `<*>` but that can be defined in terms of `liftA2`: `p <*> q = liftA2 (\f x -> f x) p q`, so you could also write that explicitly for `ZipList`:

```hs
ZipList fs <*> ZipList xs = ZipList (zipWith (\f x -> f x) fs xs)
```

Edit: I should also mention that one difference with `ZipList` is that you have an `Empty` constructor for your `IntervalMap` type. That makes things harder, you would need to know that your values have some sort of default value, but that is not possible in general (not every type has a default value), so your type cannot be an Applicative. Do you really need that `Empty` case?